# How can I force the client to re-download my website?

Tags: javascript, http, caching, go

I'm writing a web server in Go, using the `github.com/gorilla/mux` router. My program checks if the client has a cookie called "name" and based on that, serves one of two files. Here's the handler function:

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if name, err := r.Cookie("name"); err == nil && name.Value != "" {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/messager.html")
    } else {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/index.html")
    }
}
```

Testing this on Firefox, I load my website, which correctly serves `index.html` since I don't have the cookie set. In `index.html`, there's a form which sets the cookie and reloads the page when submitted.

This is the problem. The page reloads, but due to caching `index.html` is still displayed in the browser (despite the server actually serving `messager.html` - I added a debug log.) I can reload the page manually as many times as I want, making no difference, but once I do a hard refresh it works and displays `messager.html`.

This only seems to happen on Firefox (I've tested Safari, Edge, and Firefox). Any suggestions on how I can force the browser to display the correct page?

Comment: Set the appropriate headers so your page isn't cached?

Comment: I don't necessarily _not_ want it to be cached - after all, there's a reason caching exists. I just want to be able to, under certain conditions, make sure the browser uses the new version. I suppose it might be easier to just never cache it though.

Comment: Sounds like what [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)s are for.

Comment: @Flimzy it's not really about forcing/not forcing a refresh - I can do that with JavaScript. I need to make sure the browser uses the actual HTML I send to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http.ServeFile sends a Last-Modified header (with the value set to the file's mtime), and no Cache-Control header. In this case browsers will implement heuristics to determine if and how long the response may be cached.

To instruct clients not to cache a response, send the [Cache-Control header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) yourself:

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")

    if name, err := r.Cookie("name"); err == nil && name.Value != "" {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/messager.html")
    } else {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/index.html")
    }
}
```

Caution: the Cache-Control header is really unintuitive. For instance, there is a value called "no-cache", but that doesn't actually cause clients not to cache a response. Read the docs carefully to get your desired affect.

Comment: Based on your comment on the question, you may indeed be looking for something like `max-age=60, must-revalidate` plus ETags.

Comment: no-store also does not prevent caching. It prevents long term storage of the response (e.g. on disk) [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.2). If it works for you that may well be a browser quirk and not the same across all of them. `max-age=0` is the canonical value for preventing caching.